# Referring to another variable in the same object with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Alright, so I'm completely new to jQuery, so here goes:

I have a GameCard object which accepts a div in it's "constructor" which is then assigned to a variable. Within the object, I want to perform a function when that div is clicked.

```
function GameCard(imageSource, div)
{
    this.cardImage = new Image();
    this.cardImage.src = imageSource;

    this.hiddenImage = new Image();
    this.hiddenImage.src = HIDDEN_SOURCE;

    this.div = div;

    $(this).WHAT_HERE_?.click(function()
    {
    });
}
```

pretty much how do you refer to another variable within the same object using javascript?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$(this.div).click(function() {});` or if you're doing the assignment inside of the constructor you can even use the `div` parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrap the `div` using the `jQuery` function.

```
$(div).on('click',function(){
  //do stuff
});
```

Comment: So if there's multiple objects of type GameCard, this function will only apply to the object it's wrapped within?

Comment: @JohnW it will only wrap the `div`. If you want multiple objects, you can place them in an array, and wrap that array with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

What is the id of your div?

Don't use $(this) in this context.

```
$("#IdOfDiv").click(function(){});
```

But wrap the above in this;

```
$(function(){});
```

This ensures that the jQuery code is not run until the document is loaded.

So;

```
$(function(){   $("#IdOfDiv").click(function(){
     //Do someting   
  }); 
});
```